# Validate when account email is changed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, security, email-verification

Please consider validating the email when it is change in the user account.
Similar to the **"Registration Account Email Validation"**. I believe that if someone hacks your account and try to change the email, you get a validation and confirmation link by email to confirm this change.

For security reasons I think this is the correct approach. Many sites like Twitter and Facebook uses this approach.

Comment: I assume you mean the free text email field when editing the profile? In this case, that's not the email used to log in. To log in you must use OpenID provider.

Comment: Really? Didn't know. Thanks for clarifying. I got scared, because it was to easy.

Comment: I notice that it changed my Avatar so this email is used to integrate with Gravatar. That is a nice information to add there, I didn't know this also.

Comment: Yeah, looked for some official information about it and din't find any. This email is used for the gravatar indeed and also for email notifications as far as I know.

Comment: Really for notifications? Dam! :(

Comment: At some places you can choose different email but that's what appears as default and when  you choose to subscribe to a specific tag, yep.